# Identify error using Paperclip and ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, imagemagick, paperclip

I installed the Paperclip gem to upload images to my Rails app to upload images and worked fine. My `User model` looked like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :photo

has_attached_file :photo
```

I then installed ImageMagick (version 6.7.8) to edit uploaded images. For that I changed my model to include:

```
has_attached_file :photo , styles: { small: "50x50"}
```

But each time I now try to upload an image I get

```
* Photo /var/folders/UN/UNdHgXwNEJ8MFx6qXcFcck+++TI/-Tmp-/Img120120717-55617-z57m6n.jpg is not recognized by the **'identify'** command
```

In my config/environments/development.rb directory I have included:

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

But despite that error persists. FYI, I am working on an OS 10.5.8.

Please help!

Comment: What happens if you feed the jpg to identify on the terminal?

Comment: On the command line, in the ImageMagick directory, on typing: "identify rose.jpg", I get rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 DirectClass 87kb 0.050u 0:01. So, I guess the "identify" command of ImageMagick is working but the Rails App or Paperclip cannot link up with ImageMagick.

Comment: Can you move the file to the authentic position, give it the respective name and try again? This would exclude a problem with the exotic characters.

Comment: How do I move the file (by file, I assume you mean the image) to the authentic position and give it the respective name?

Comment: Your rails app is complaining that the identify command can't handle the file `/var/folders/UN/UNdHgXwNEJ8MFx6qXcFcck+++TI/-Tmp-/Img120120717-55617-z57m6n.jpg` which would be the authentic position. Perhaps there is a problem with the special chars within the path?

Comment: Which Cocaine version are you using? Try switching back to `0.3.2` if you are using `0.4.0`.. Worked for me..